# Is there a way to add a Jasmine matcher to the whole environment

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-matchers

There are plenty of documents that show how to add a matcher to a Jasmine spec ([here](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Matchers), for example).

Has anyone found a way to add matchers to the whole environment; I'm wanting to create a set of useful matchers to be called by any and all tests, without copypasta all over my specs.

Currently working to reverse engineer the source, but would prefer a tried and true method, if one exists.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Sure, you just call `beforeEach()` without any spec scoping at all, and add matchers there.

This would globally add a `toBeOfType` matcher.

```
beforeEach(function() {
  var matchers = {
    toBeOfType: function(typeString) {
      return typeof this.actual == typeString;
    }
  };

  this.addMatchers(matchers);
});

describe('Thing', function() {
  // matchers available here.
});
```

I've made a file named `spec_helper.js` full of things like custom matchers that I just need to load onto the page before I run the rest of the spec suite.

Comment: I also found a nice example here: http://tobyho.com/2012/01/30/write-a-jasmine-matcher/

Comment: I tried link shared by Dancrumb, ideally its neat and clean approach however it didn't work so I adopted Alex approach.

Comment: Here's one for jasmine 2.0+

````javascript
beforeEach(function(){
  jasmine.addMatchers({
    toEqualData: function() {
      return {
        compare: function(actual, expected) {
          return { pass: angular.equals(actual, expected) }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
````

Comment: @mikker You should edit the answer or post your own rather than leaving that in a comment. http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: @Dancrumb, there is a problem with defining matcher like that. It adds to `jasmine.Matchers.prototype` well, but it doesn't actually assert statements. I mean following: `expect(false).toBeTruthyCustom()` will execute, but it will not produce a failure.

Answer (score 14):

Here's one for jasmine 2.0+:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  jasmine.addMatchers({
    toEqualData: function() {
      return {
        compare: function(actual, expected) {
          return { pass: angular.equals(actual, expected) };
        }
      };
    }
  });
});
```

Note that this uses angular's `angular.equals`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.. writing out compare's arguments is always an empty object.

Comment: That's the answer I've been looking for!

Comment: **For detailed answer see:** [Create custom Jasmine-Matcher using Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49405171/8740349)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I didn't know it was an internal implementation that may be subjected to change. Use at your own risk.

```
jasmine.Expectation.addCoreMatchers(matchers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous answers, I created the following setup for **angular-cli**. I also need an external module in my matcher (in this case moment.js)

**Note** In this example I added an equalityTester, but it should work with a customer matcher

Create a file `src/spec_helper.ts` with the following contents:

```
// Import module
import { Moment } from 'moment';

export function initSpecHelper() {

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Add your matcher
    jasmine.addCustomEqualityTester((a: Moment, b: Moment) => {
      if (typeof a.isSame === 'function') {
        return a.isSame(b);
      }
    });
  });

}
```

Then, in `src/test.ts` import the `initSpecHelper()` function add execute it. I placed it before Angular's TestBed init, wich seems to work just fine.

```
import { initSpecHelper } from './spec_helper';

//...

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () {};

// Init our own spec helper
initSpecHelper();

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

//...
```