# Checking two boundaries with Jasmine (between matcher)

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, assertions, jasmine-matchers

In Jasmine, there are `toBeGreaterThan` and `toBeLessThan` matchers.

What if I want to check an integer value in a specific range? Is there anything like `toBeInBetween` matcher?

Currently, I can solve it in two separate `expect` calls:

```
var x = 3;

expect(x).toBeGreaterThan(1);
expect(x).toBeLessThan(10);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can run the boolean comparison and assert the result is `true`:

```
expect(x > 1 && x < 10).toBeTruthy();
```

Also, there is `toBeWithinRange()` custom matcher introduced by [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers):

```
expect(x).toBeWithinRange(2, 9);  // range borders are included
```