# Can you chain multiple Jasmine matchers?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm a beginner web developer who is making my first personal Jasmine suite for testing one of my school projects. I ran into an issue when creating specs for a JS function I wrote that generates a random number between 1 and 20. An error occurred when I tried to chain multiple matchers together like this

```
        it("Should return an integer value between 1 and 20.", function(){
            var rollResult=rollD20();
            expect(rollResult).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1).toBeLessThanOrEqual(20);
        });
```

Am I missing something simple? Is there a way to apply multiple matchers in one statement or is the proper approach to split it up into multiple lines like this:

```
        it("Should return an integer value between 1 and 20.", function(){
            var rollResult=rollD20();
            //CHECK WITH SEAN. CAN YOU CHAIN?
            expect(rollResult).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1);
            expect(rollResult).toBeLessThanOrEqual(20);
        });
```

I appreciate any help! I was struggled finding a clear answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can chain. You can change what's inside of the `expect` though.

```
expect(rollResult >= 1 && rollResult <= 20).toBeTrue();
```

I got this inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28732882/7365461) answer.