# Combine "toHaveBeenCalledWith" and "toBeCloseTo"

Tags: jasmine

I need a way to check if a spy was called with an approximate value, like it can be done with `expect(value).toBeCloseTo(3,2)`.

Something like this:

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("some string", valueToBeCloseTo(3, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `calls` and `mostRecent` helpers.

```
const secondArgument = spy.calls.mostRecent().args[1]; // args[0] would be the string
expect(secondArgument).toBeLessThanOrEqual(3);
expect(secondArgument).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(2);
```

Check out this [link](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction) for most recent and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48883894/7365461) for `toBeLessThanOrEqual` and `toBeGreaterThanOrEqual`.