# Custom jasmine matchers and protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

We've added a `toHaveClass` *custom jasmine matcher* and, in order to make it work, we had to add it to `beforeEach()` (with the help of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942085/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-jasmine-matcher-to-the-whole-environment)).

And, to follow the DRY principle and to avoid repeating the matcher definition in every `beforeEach()` in specs where `toHaveClass` is needed, we've added a `beforeEach()` block right into `onPrepare()`:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    var jasmineReporters = require("jasmine-reporters");
    require("jasmine-expect");

    // ...

    // custom matchers
    beforeEach(function() {
        jasmine.addMatchers({
            toHaveClass: function() {
                return {
                    compare: function(actual, expected) {
                        return {
                            pass: actual.getAttribute("class").then(function(classes) {
                                return classes.split(" ").indexOf(expected) !== -1;
                            })
                        };
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    });
},
```

It actually works, but every time I see `beforeEach()` block inside the protractor config, I have a micro-depression and a strong feeling it is not a good place to define matchers.

**The Question:**

Is there a better way or place to have custom matchers defined?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most simple solution I see is to move this `beforeEach` block to a separate file and require it inside `onPrepare`, like you do with vendor libs:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    var jasmineReporters = require("jasmine-reporters");
    require("jasmine-expect");
    require('./tests/support/jasmine-custom-matchers'); // inject custom matchers
    // ....
}
```

The code of the `beforeEach` should not require any changes:

```
// /tests/support/jasmine-custom-matchers.js

beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toHaveClass: function() {
            return {
                compare: function(actual, expected) {
                    return {
                        pass: actual.getAttribute("class").then(function(classes) {
                            return classes.split(" ").indexOf(expected) !== -1;
                        })
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    });
});
```

I do not think you should `export` something from this file though, it will take effect by just `require`-ing it.

Comment: This helped me add the additional "jasmine-expect" matchers to protractor! Just had to add the `require("jasmine-expect");` like you have, and then add the types from "npm i -D @types/jasmine-expect" to tsconfig.json `"types":["jasmine", "node", "jasmine-expect"]`