# Create custom jasmine matcher using Typescript

Tags: typescript, jasmine, jasmine-matchers

I'm using jasmine on an angular2 project and having some trouble writing a custom matcher for a test. I want to be able to compare two relatively complex objects. I found [this article](http://www.tomdoescode.co.uk/2016/06/jasmine-custom-matchers-with-typescript.html) which claims to solve the issue but it simply results in a typescript error stating that it doesn't recognize the new method on jasmine's `Matchers` object. The relevant code is this:

```
declare module jasmine {
    interface Matchers {
        toBeNumeric(): void;
    }
}
```

[Another article](https://medium.com/@cwmrowe/making-jasmine-and-typescript-play-nicely-c2f4bef1830a#.72pdxywdl) gives a similar, but slightly different solution that gives the same error.

```
declare namespace jasmine {
    interface Matchers {
        toHaveText(expected: string): boolean;
    }
}
```

I tried this

```
let m: jasmine.Matchers = expect(someSpy.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

and got this error:

> Type 'jasmine.Matchers' is not assignable to type 'jasmine.Matchers'.
>   Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.

That seems to indicate that the `declare namespace jasmine` statement is creating a new `jasmine` namespace rather than extending the existing one.

So how can I create my own matcher that typescript will be happy with?

Comment: **See also [matchers which work in all versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50714959/8740349)**

Answer (score 15):

Daf's answer mostly worked for me I just noticed an issue with his sample code and the way he named his files. I also happened upon another unrelated issue. Hence a new answer.

- For some reason my app does not like it when the interface file has the same name as the matcher file. e.g foo.ts and foo.d.ts. For my app it needed to be foo.ts and foo-interface.d.ts or something like it.
- Also don't import interfaces from foo.ts into foo-interface.d.ts it also does not seem to like this.

**Matcher - custom-matchers.ts**

```
import MatchersUtil = jasmine.MatchersUtil;
import CustomMatcherFactories = jasmine.CustomMatcherFactories;
import CustomEqualityTester = jasmine.CustomEqualityTester;
import CustomMatcher = jasmine.CustomMatcher;
import CustomMatcherResult = jasmine.CustomMatcherResult;

export const SomeCustomMatchers: CustomMatcherFactories = {
    toReallyEqual: function (util: MatchersUtil, customEqualityTester: CustomEqualityTester[]): CustomMatcher {
        return {
            compare: function (actual: any, expected: any, anotherCustomArg: any): CustomMatcherResult {

                // Your checks here.
                const passes = actual === expected;

                // Result and message generation.
                return {
                    pass: passes,
                    message: passes ? `Actual equals expected`
                                    : `Actual does not equal expected`,
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> **NOTE** that `compare` function can have as many custom-parameters as we want (or even Variadic),
> and that ONLY first-argument is required/reserved (to know actual-value);
> but if the function name begins with "`toHave`" (instead of `toReallyEqual`), then the second argument is reserved for "`key: string`" (to know object's field name, I mean, Jasmine2 will loop for us).
>
> Also, we could relay on Jasmine for message-generation, like:
>
> ```
> message: util.buildFailureMessage('toReallyEqual', passes, actual, expected, anotherCustomArg),
> ```

**Interface file - matcher-types.d.ts - cannot be the same name as your matcher file**

```
declare namespace jasmine {
    interface Matchers<T> {
        toReallyEqual(expected: any, anotherCustomArg: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
    }
}
```

**Custom matcher test**

```
describe('Hello', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        jasmine.addMatchers(SomeCustomMatchers)
    });

    it('should allow custom matchers', () => {
        expect('foo').toReallyEqual('foo');
        expect('bar').not.toReallyEqual('test');
    })
});
```

Comment: Two small observations: In the definition of the `toReallyEqual` function you use the parameter `customEqualityTester` that is an array of `jasmine.CustomEqualityTester`, so considering that this is an array a better name could be `customEqualityTesters` (plural).

Comment: Second observation is that when you have a `return` inside an `if` sentence you don't need to have the `else`.

Comment: +1 This approach works (perfectly).  I've seen other suggestions elsewhere that suggest you can have the 'declare namespace' in the spec file but, for whatever reason, typescript does not merge the interfaces when you do that.

Comment: It's not only "your app" that does not like when files are named the same, only with different extensions. See this for a simple explanation: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7624.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, your second example ("declare namespace") is the way to go, with your logic for the matchers somewhere else, of course.

You're welcome to take a look at https://github.com/fluffynuts/polymer-ts-scratch/tree/5eb799f7c8d144dd8239ab2d2bcc72821327cb24/src/specs/test-utils/jasmine-matchers where I have written some Jasmine matchers and typings to go along with them -- though technically I wrote the actual matchers in Javascript and just named the logic files .ts to placate my build process.

You *will* need to install `@types/jasmine` -- and keep it current.

Just bear in mind that different versions of `@types/jasmine` may break things; specifically, the commit linked above was when Jasmine types introduced the `Matchers` type having a type parameter (ie, `Matchers<T>`) which broke all my .d.ts files.

Comment: Thanks @daf - I patterned my example off yours, and it works at runtime but typescript still complains `TS2339: Property 'toEqualWithoutSymbol' does not exist on type 'Matchers<void>'.`  Not sure what I'm missing, but the file is definitely included (because typescript runs it).

Comment: I figured out a bunch of extra triple slash directives were giving me false errors.  I cleaned up the old project and those errors went away.  So this sample project works great!

Comment: Thanks a lot for linking your example files, that helped me work out my issue. In my case, I was missing the generic `<T>` on the `Matchers` interface.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ES modules then the namespace declaration needs to be wrapped in a `declare global` block.

Here is the updated example with both custom matchers merged into the same definition:

```
    declare global {
        namespace jasmine {
            interface Matchers {
                toBeNumeric(): void;
                toHaveText(expected: string): boolean;
            }
        }
    }
```

It's also possible to have the declarations split apart (or even spread across multiple files):

```
    // File 1 declares this matcher
    declare global {
        namespace jasmine {
            interface Matchers {
                toBeNumeric(): void;
            }
        }
    }

    // File 2 declares this matcher
    declare global {
        namespace jasmine {
            interface Matchers {
                toHaveText(expected: string): boolean;
            }
        }
    }

    // File 3: use the custom matchers
    it(function(){
        expect(3).toBeNumeric();
        expect(result).toHaveText('custom matcher');
    });
```

NOTE: In these snippets the `namespace` and `module` keywords are equivalent but `module` is deprecated and `namespace` is preferred (to avoid confusion with ES modules or CommonJS modules).

Answer (score 0):

All previous solutions didn't work for me so I have done it yet a bit different way:

**shared-custom-matchers.ts**

```
import MatchersUtil = jasmine.MatchersUtil;
import CustomMatcher = jasmine.CustomMatcher;
import CustomMatcherResult = jasmine.CustomMatcherResult;
import Constructor = jasmine.Constructor;

declare global {
  namespace jasmine {
    interface Matchers<T> {
      toBeInstanceExactlyOf(expected: Constructor): boolean;
    }
  }
}

export let sharedCustomMatchers = {
  toBeInstanceExactlyOf: function (util: MatchersUtil): CustomMatcher {
    return {
      compare: function (actual: any, expected: Constructor): CustomMatcherResult {
        if (actual instanceof expected &&
          actual.constructor.name === expected.name &&
          actual.constructor.valueOf() === expected.valueOf()) {
          return {
            pass: true,
            message: `Instance is exactly of type`
          };
        } else {
          return {
            pass: false,
            message: `Instance (${actual.constructor.valueOf()}) is not exactly of type (${expected.valueOf()})`
          };
        }
      }
    };
  }
};
```

**sut.spec.ts** (only relevant parts)

```
import { sharedCustomMatchers } from "../common/shared-custom-matchers";

beforeEach(() => {
  jasmine.addMatchers(sharedCustomMatchers);
```