# How do I add a Jasmine custom matcher Typescript definition?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, jasmine

I've been [looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956195/create-custom-jasmine-matcher-using-typescript) [around](http://www.tomdoescode.co.uk/2016/06/jasmine-custom-matchers-with-typescript.html) and this question seems like a [recurring thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules). However, none of the solutions I've found seem to work for me.

Using the following:

```
{
  "typescript": "2.3.2",
  "jasmine-core": "2.6.1",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47"
}
```

I can't get Typescript to merge the namespace declaration containing my custom matcher definition.

Adding this:

```
declare namespace jasmine {
  interface Matchers<T> {
    toBeAnyOf(expected: jasmine.Expected<T>, expectationFailOutput?: any): boolean;
  }
}
```

Hides every other type previously declared on `jasmine`. Compiler outputs errors such as:

```
[ts] Namespace 'jasmine' has no exported member 'CustomMatcherFactories'
[ts] Namespace 'jasmine' has no exported member 'CustomMatcher'.
```

Is there any proper way to add a custom matcher and make it play nicely with Typescript?

There's an additional issue with `tslint` if you are using `tslint:recommended` ruleset. Those rules disallow the usage of `namespace` or `module` keywords, so I had to disable the linter (or change the `"no-namespace"` rule) in order to try this out. Unsure how one would get around extending definitions if this is "not recommended".

Comment: Did the answer below end up solving your problem Nicolas or did you do something else?

Comment: @hornairs This happened a while ago, but I seem to recall that it didn't. In the end, I gave up and re-wrote my test using already available matchers.

Answer (score 8):

I had to modify three files when I added custom matchers. I created a file called matchers.ts that contained the actual matchers. I then added an import to test.ts for my matchers.ts file. Finally, I added an interface to the typings.d.ts file which contains my matcher.

matchers.ts (arbitrary name)

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toContainText: () => {
            return {
                compare: (actual: HTMLElement, expectedText: string, customMessage?: string) => {
                    const actualText = actual.textContent;
                    return {
                        pass: actualText.indexOf(expectedText) > -1,
                        get message() {
                            let failureMessage = 'Expected ' + actualText + ' to contain ' + expectedText;

                            if (customMessage) {
                                failureMessage = ' ' + customMessage;
                            }

                            return failureMessage;
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        },
    });
});
```

test.ts

```
import 'test/test-helpers/global/matchers'; (my relative filepath)
```

typings.d.ts

```
declare module jasmine {
  interface Matchers {
    toContainText(text: string, message?: string): boolean;
  }
}
```

Comment: The 'declare' statement can perfectly be happily stuck in the spec.ts file.

Comment: I had to also add triple slash directive to the tested file in order to get rid of message: _TS2339: Property 'toContainText' does not exist on type 'Matchers<T>_:  `///<reference path="./typings.d.ts"/>` and add generic type to the `Matchers`: Matchers **<T>**.

Comment: [tslint] The internal 'module' syntax is deprecated, use the 'namespace' keyword instead. (no-internal-module)

Comment: Create a separate file for typings.d.ts

Comment: Comming accross this issue again and again:( this helped a little: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/462#issuecomment-345540263