# Use Jasmine custom matcher with Angular CLI project

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-matchers

I have a simple need: to use my own custom matchers in Jasmine unit tests within an Angular CLI project (Angular v6).
A couple constraints:

- I do not want to modify anything under node_modules; this project has to be able to go through my build pipeline which does a clean install every time.
- I do not want to have to build an npm module just to be able to add to `types` in tsconfig.spec.json.

What I have been able to discern so far is that I need a .d.ts file, so this is my matchers.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts" />

declare namespace jasmine {
  interface Matchers<T> {
    toContainPath(path: string): boolean;
  }
}
```

In the same directory I have my matchers.ts file:

```
export const customMatchers: jasmine.CustomMatcherFactories  = {

  // Affirms the element contains a sub-element at the given CSS path.
  toContainPath: function (_util, _customEqualityTesters) {
    return {
      compare: function (element: HTMLElement, path: string) {
        const result = {
          pass: false,
          message: ''
        };
        if (!element) {
          result.message = 'Expected element to be non-empty';
        } else if (!path) {
          result.message = 'Expected path to be non-empty';
        } else {
          result.pass = element.querySelector(path) !== null;
          result.message =
            'Expected ' + element + (result.pass ? ' not' : '') + ' to contain ' + path;
        }
        return result;
      }
    };
  }
};
```

In my test (spec) file, I have:

```
import { customMatchers } from 'app/testing/matchers';
. . .
/// <reference path="../../../testing/matchers.d.ts" />
. . .
 beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.addMatchers(customMatchers);
. . .
```

and finally, I use the matcher in included tests with, e.g.:

```
expect(element).toContainPath('my-sidebar');
```

I also tried adding the full path of matchers.d.ts to the `types` array in tsconfig.spec.json.

Alas, I have not been able to find a solution that works. The failure continues to manifest as
`error TS2339: Property 'toContainPath' does not exist on type 'Matchers<HTMLElement>'`

Promising places I looked, but to no avail:

1. [custom jasmine matchers](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5456)
2. [adding a jasmine matcher TypeScript definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787900/how-do-i-add-a-jasmine-custom-matcher-typescript-definition)
3. [jasmine matchers](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers)
4. [testing Angular with custom matchers](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/12/27/angular-2-advance-testing-with-custom-matchers.html)
5. [manually add typing file to TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473654/angular-how-to-manually-add-typing-file-to-typescript)

Could anyone offer the secret sauce?

Answer (score 1):

The two answers here combined ended up working for me!

[Create custom jasmine matcher using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956195/create-custom-jasmine-matcher-using-typescript)

Added an index.ts to the testing folder and made the .ts and .d.ts files have different names (e.g. custom-matchers.ts and matchers-types.d.ts).

Comment: could you please elaborate what is supposed to be inside index.ts?