# How to add custom matchers to jasmine globally?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, matcher, jasmine-matchers

I'd need a replacement for the `jasmine.addMatchers` function gone in version 1.3. The current API allows to add matchers to a `describe` block, but I'd prefer to be able to use my matchers everywhere without adding them again and again.

Is there a *global* way to add own matchers to jasmine 3.1.0?

Comment: Have you tried creating a module of the matchers and just instantiating them wherever you want to use them?

Comment: @ManuelBlanco No, I actually don't have a clue how to do it. Anyway, I'd like my matchers to be available everywhere without any additional work, just like the build-in matchers are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/JamieMason/add-matchers can be used to write matchers which work in all versions of Jasmine, as well as Jest.

```
var addMatchers = require('add-matchers');

addMatchers({
  // matcher with 0 arguments
  toBeEvenNumber: function(received) {
    // received : 4
    return received % 2 === 0;
  },
  // matcher with 1 argument
  toBeOfType: function(type, received) {
    // type     : 'Object'
    // received : {}
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(received) === '[object ' + type + ']';
  },
  // matcher with many arguments
  toContainItems: function(arg1, arg2, arg3, received) {
    // arg1     : 2
    // arg2     : 15
    // arg3     : 100
    // received : [100, 14, 15, 2]
    return (
      received.indexOf(arg1) !== -1 &&
      received.indexOf(arg2) !== -1 &&
      received.indexOf(arg3) !== -1
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that I have not tried this in jasmine 3.1, but this is how I am doing the same in jasmine 2.8:

Place this in any code block that gets run before your tests:

```
jasmine.getEnv().beforeEach(() => {
  jasmine.addMatchers({
    toBeAwesome(util, customEqualityTesters) { ... }
  })
});
```

Comment: The question acknowledges this is possible ("The current API allows to add matchers to a describe block") and states that it is insufficient for purposes of the question ("I'd prefer to be able to use my matchers everywhere without adding them again and again").

Comment: This code does not need to be in a describe block. It can be anywhere, even be placed in the global scope if you like, as long as it is run before your tests. It is essentially creating a global `beforeEach` that is not tied to a single describe. So, technically, yes these matchers are still being added for each describe block, but for the purposes of your own code you only need to specify them once.

Comment: This global `beforeEach` sounds hacky, but I guess, it'd do what I want. I've tried the other solution first and it it worked, so I'll stick with it.

Comment: This is a much better answer than `add-matcher` lib. `add-matcher` is awesome but doesn't allow you to customize failure messages like you can do with matchers written for Jasmine. Also you can swap `beforeAll` instead of `beforeEach` and it should be a little better.

Comment: And what file is this supposed to be written in? (remember all tests have random run-order)

Answer (score 0):

With `jasmine-core` version 3.8 (possibly already with 3.1) the answer by [Andrew Eisenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50711968/9740071) no longer works.
Therefore I have created a `beforeAll()` outside my tests (= outside of all `describe`-blocks), which is thereby executed before all tests.

> If you work with Angular you can place it in `src/test.ts`.

Inside the `beforeAll()` I simply call `jasmine.addMatchers(myCustomMatcher)`:

```js
beforeAll(() => jasmine.addMatchers(myCustomMatcher));
```